# Appending string using python

Tags: python

I need to append to a string. The final string should display like this:

```
"""
       One Man
       TWO woman
       FRUITS == "Mango" # "Grapes" # "Banana" 
       VEGE == "Carrot" # "Cabbage" # "Chillie" 

"""
```

This is the way I am building the `fruits` string

```
def findFruit(f):
    global fruits
    for ww in f.strip().split():

        if ww.startswith(('Man','Gra','Bana')):
            fruits+= ww
```

Main (This is where i am constructing the string):

```
finalString =     """
           One Man
           TWO woman
           FRUITS == """ + fruits +
           """
           VEGE == "Carrot" # "Cabbage" # "Chillie" 
           """
```

As you see the string concatenation i have used doesn't resemble the expected output. How can i solve this? I need it to be EXACTLY as the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[string.join()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) could be used for efficient string concatenation:

```
def findFruit(f):
    global fruits
    fruits = ' # '.join('"{}"'.format(s) for s in f.strip().split() if s.startswith(('Man', 'Gra', 'Bana')))


>>> fruits
'"Mango" # "Grape" # "Banana"'
```

Comment: It doesn't always start with a `#` there's no `#` in front of the text `Mango`

Comment: `string.join()` inserts the `string` only inbetween joined stings, neither at the beginning nor at the end. See output.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
def findFruit(f):
global fruits
    for ww in f.strip().split():

        if ww.startswith(('Man','Gra','Bana')):
            fruits+= '\"%s\" #' % ww
    fruits = fruits[0:-1]
```

Comment: Need to fix indentation with `global fruits`.

Comment: I get an error NameError: global name 'fruits' is not defined